# Plugin to write a patch file while editing files in vim

Tags: vim

I often have to edit some config files on a server and at the same time document the changes. Now I had the idea that we could have a plugin to automatically log all the changes to the file to an external patch file.

Before I try to hack up something myself - is there a plugin that does something like this already?

I'm thinking about some command ala

```
:LogChanges /tmp/changes.patch
```

After which all changes in (all files|the current file) would be logged to said patch file.

Comment: You knew someone would ask this: why not using a VCS like git to document such changes? :) To answer: I don't know about any plugin that does exactly what you asked for. Maybe http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Create_patch_for_currently_editing_file ?

Comment: exactly just do a git patch instead.